# Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null

Tags: javascript

The error message I am getting is `Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null`:

```
var b = document.getElementById('chat-messages');
b.scrollTop = b.scrollHeight;

var lst = b.scrollTop;
console.log(lst);

b.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (b.scrollTop > lst) {
    console.log("Greater than Last");
  } else {
    console.log("Less or equal than last.");
  }

  lst = b.scrollTop;
});
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `chat-messages` on the page before this script executes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733040/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-scrollheight-of-undefined)

Comment: make sure that script executes after loading chat-messages into dom

Comment: yes i had a chat-messages on the page before this script

Comment: Please refer to this answer , Hope this helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381817/how-do-i-determine-scrollheight

Comment: Let's see the HTML.

Comment: Show your HTML code. If possible can you put this code in Fiddle or Codepen or Plunker?

Comment: do you have any element id as chat-messages

Comment: yes i had an element id as chat-messages

Comment: show your html code

Answer (score 0):

Correct ways in jQuery are -

$('#chat-messages').prop('scrollHeight') OR
   $('#chat-messages')[0].scrollHeight

Hope it helps.

Comment: $('#chat-messages').scrollTop($('#chat-messages')[0].scrollHeight); i used this code but same error coming