# Auto scroll to bottom of the page using overflow auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component

i have created a chat application using vue js. i use overflow: auto for my div. What i want is to automatically scroll on the bottom of the div so that users will no longer click the scroll to view the latest message. My code does not work and it shows no error in the console. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

here is the code

```
    <template>
 <div class="panel-block">
        <div class="chat" v-if="chats.length != 0" id="myDiv">
         <div v-for="chat in chats" style="overflow: auto;">
             <div class="chat-right" v-if="chat.user_id == userid">
                 {{ chat.chat }}
             </div>
             <div class="chat-left" v-else>

                 {{ chat.chat}}
             </div>
         </div>

        </div>
        <div v-else class="no-message">
            <br>
            There are no messages
        </div>
        <chat-composer v-bind:userid="userid" v-bind:chats="chats" v-bind:adminid="adminid"></chat-composer>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    props: ['chats','userid','adminid', 'onlineuserss'],
}

$(document).ready(function(){
var myDiv = $("#myDiv");
myDiv.animate({ scrollTop: myDiv.prop("scrollHeight") - myDiv.height() }, 3000);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Why did you add laravel tag ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code which should keep you at the bottom of the div rather than overflow: auto.

```
var chatWindow = document.getElementById("chat in chats");
    chatWindow.scrollTop = chatWindow.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: i get this error when i tried your code - Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903629/cannot-read-property-scrollheight-of-null Does this help solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
  scrollToEnd () {
      var container = this.$el.querySelector('#myDiv')
      container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to give your scrolling element an ID so you can select it easily.
Then we want to set the scrollTop value of that object equal to the scrollHeight when the data gets updated. In vue we can do that by calling nextTick() after the data gets updated.

Howerver, when we only do this the chat will keep scrolling down on each new message, this is usually not what you want, because this means that when your user scrolls up, the chat keeps scrolling back down with each new message. In order to let the chat only scroll down when we're already scrolled to the bottom we can check if the user has scrolled up, and only if that's not the case, we auto-scroll down. The final code looks like this, you have to do this in the function that updates the data, after the data has been updated.

```
var chatWindow = document.getElementById('chat-id-here')
var isScrolled = (chatWindow.scrollTop < chatWindow.scrollHeight - chatWindow.offsetHeight - 10)

Vue.nextTick(function () {
  if (!isScrolled) {
    chatWindow.scrollTop = chatWindow.scrollHeight
  }
})
```

Note that the '- 10' at the 'isScrolled' variable, is the amount of pixels the user has to scroll up before we stop autoscrolling, so you can adjust this as you see fit.

Comment: im getting this error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of null

Comment: Did you give the scrolling div an id attribute? We can't select the element with document.getElementById() if the element does not have an id.

Comment: i added window.onload and does not show any errors but the scroll is still on top of the div.

Comment: Since you're using Vue, you'll want to put your javascript code in your Vue components. Vue components have their own place for code that needs to load when a component initializes. 

window.onload and document.ready() will only work on the initial pageload. But after that, the pages never really loads again, it's just Vue updating all the elements in the DOM dynamically. 

Vue has some great documentation that you can take a look at over here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/